# Вызов секции на страницы

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Всем привет! Подскажите как мне с помощью js вызвать определенный блок. Вообщем ситуация такая в вордпресс есть файл heder там шапка и блок с под меню. Нужно что бы на разных страницах вызывались свои блоки. Или есть другой способ

Comment: Это должно делаться на сервере в коде php

Comment: Можно же и js в html. Ну если знаешь как с помощью php это сделать, рад буду услышать!)

Comment: это извращение и лишняя нагрузка на ком клиента. Все страницы в WP строятся динамически, с помощью php, так почему не добавить немного функционала туда. Но без кода, которым выводится header, на вопрос ответить нельзя. Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: +100500 - это ДИКОЕ извращение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно на пхп это сделать в header.php

```
if (is_single(ID нужной страницы или слаг страницы)) {
   ...вывод нужных блоков
} else {
   ...вывод старых блоков и меню
}
```